# Pandas. How to call data frame from the list of data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a list of data frames:

```
all_df = ['df_0','df_1','df_2','df_3','df_4','df_5','df_6']
```

How can I call them from this list to do something like that:

```
for (df,names) in zip(all_df,names):
   df.to_csv('output/{}.csv'.format(names))
```

When executing expectedly I'm getting error `'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'` since I'm giving string to the `'to_csv'`.

How can I save several data-frames (or perform other actions on them) in the `for` loop?

Thanks!

Could you please also give an idea on how to create the 'right' list of data frames from this:

```
path = 'inp/multysheet_excel_01.xlsx'
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
sh_name = xl.sheet_names

n = 0
for i in sh_name:
    exec('df_{} = pd.read_excel("{}", sheet_name="{}")'.format(n, path, i))
    n+=1
```

so basically I'm trying to get the each sheet of an input excel as a separate dataframe, perform some actions on them, and save each output dataframe in separate excels.

Comment: `all_df` is not the list of dataframes, its is the list of strings hence you are getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

You're quite close, but I see some mistakes in that for loop. Say you have a list of dataframes `dfs`, and its corresponding names as a list of strings `names`, you can save those dataframes using the names as:

```
dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3]
names = ['df_0','df_1','df_2']

for df,name in zip(dfs,names):
    df.to_csv('output\\{}.csv'.format(name))
```

Though if you only had a list of names, you could also do something like:

```
names = ['df_0','df_1','df_2']
for name in names:
    globals()[name].to_csv('output\\{}.csv'.format(name))
```

Comment: How can I get the "right" df list from this: 
`xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
sh_name = xl.sheet_names

n = 0
for i in sh_name:
    exec('df_{} = pd.read_excel("{}", sheet_name="{}")'.format(n, path, i))
    n+=1 `

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you include this in the question, making it a reproducible example? @doctor

Comment: yep, did non know that there will be a problem with formatting

Comment: So is that piece of code generating the dataframes? @doctor

Comment: No and thats the problem. How to make it to generate dfs?) Adding something like `df_list.append('df_' + str(n))` will give a list of strings instead of list of dfs

Comment: And `sh_name ` is an iterable with the sheets? Looks ok to me really

Comment: I must say this seems like a different question though. I'd kindly encourage you to ask a new question here in SO, since the initial question seemed to be more specifically about what I initially gave an answer to @doctor